# Ubuntu can't apt-get upgrade

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apt-get

I tried to Upgrade Ubuntu from 14 to 15, and during the process I ran into some issues. The upgrade said it completed successfully but there were errors in the process. I then restarted my computer and It wouldn't start. So I then got a Live CD and followed the steps here:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCdRecovery#Update_Failure

On step 9

```
apt-get upgrade
```

I get the following message:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  jmeter-help libcgmanager0:i386 libgnome-media-profiles-3.0-0 libidl-common
  libidl0 libjpeg62 libmirclient7 libmirclientplatform-mesa
  libmono-addins-gui0.2-cil libmono-addins0.2-cil libnih-dbus1:i386
  libnih1:i386 liborbit2 python-support
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  account-plugin-aim account-plugin-jabber account-plugin-salut
  account-plugin-yahoo appmenu-qt5 aptdaemon bzip2 cabextract cheese
  cheese-common colord compiz compiz-core compiz-gnome compiz-plugins
  compiz-plugins-default console-setup cpp curl dictionaries-common
  dnsmasq-base empathy empathy-common fonts-thai-tlwg fop g++ gcc gdb
  gir1.2-clutter-1.0 gir1.2-cogl-1.0 gir1.2-coglpango-1.0 gir1.2-nmgtk-1.0
  gir1.2-totem-1.0 gnome-orca gnome-session-flashback gnome-sudoku
  gnome-terminal gnome-terminal-data gnome-tweak-tool gstreamer1.0-clutter hud
  imagemagick indicator-appmenu initscripts isc-dhcp-client isc-dhcp-common
  jmeter jmeter-http keyboard-configuration libaccount-plugin-1.0-0
  libaccounts-qt5-1 libatk-bridge2.0-0 libatk-bridge2.0-0:i386
  libatk-bridge2.0-dev libblas3 libbz2-1.0 libbz2-dev libcheese-gtk23
  libcheese7 libcloog-isl4 libclutter-1.0-0 libclutter-1.0-dev
  libclutter-gst-2.0-0 libclutter-gtk-1.0-0 libcogl-dev libcogl-pango-dev
  libcompizconfig0 libcurl3 libcurl3-gnutls libcurl4-openssl-dev libdecoration0
  libfop-java libfreerdp-plugins-standard libgcrypt11-dev libgexiv2-2
  libgnutls-dev libgnutls-openssl27 libgtlcore0.8 libgtlfragment0.8
  libgtlimageio0.8 libhud2 liblog-message-simple-perl libmm-glib0
  libnm-gtk-common libnm-gtk0 libnunit-cil-dev libopenctl0.8
  libopencv-calib3d2.4 libopencv-contrib2.4 libopencv-core2.4
  libopencv-features2d2.4 libopencv-flann2.4 libopencv-highgui2.4
  libopencv-imgproc2.4 libopencv-legacy2.4 libopencv-ml2.4
  libopencv-objdetect2.4 libopencv-photo2.4 libopencv-video2.4 libopenshiva0.8
  liboxideqt-qmlplugin liboxideqtcore0 liboxideqtquick0 libpam-modules
  libpam-modules-bin libpam-systemd libprotobuf-dev libpulse-dev
  libpulse-mainloop-glib0 libpulse0 libpulse0:i386 libpulsedsp libpython-stdlib
  libpython2.7 libpython2.7-minimal libpython2.7-stdlib libqt5core5a
  libqt5dbus5 libqt5feedback5 libqt5gui5 libqt5multimedia5 libqt5network5
  libqt5opengl5 libqt5organizer5 libqt5positioning5 libqt5printsupport5
  libqt5qml-graphicaleffects libqt5qml5 libqt5quick5 libqt5sensors5 libqt5sql5
  libqt5sql5-sqlite libqt5svg5 libqt5test5 libqt5webkit5
  libqt5webkit5-qmlwebkitplugin libqt5widgets5 libqt5xml5 librtmp-dev
  libsignon-extension1 libstk0c2a libtotem-plparser18 libtotem0 libunityvoice1
  libwacom-common libwacom2 libxml2 libxml2:i386 libxml2-dev lvm2
  mcp-account-manager-uoa metacity metacity-common modemmanager
  mysql-client-5.6 mysql-common mysql-server-5.6 mysql-server-core-5.6
  network-manager network-manager-gnome network-manager-pptp
  network-manager-pptp-gnome opengtl-dev oxideqt-codecs parted playonlinux ppp
  pulseaudio pulseaudio-module-bluetooth pulseaudio-module-x11 pulseaudio-utils
  python python-aptdaemon python-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets python-lxml
  python-minimal python-pycurl python-requests python-twisted-core
  python-twisted-web python-urllib3 python2.7 python2.7-minimal
  python3-aptdaemon python3-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets python3-aptdaemon.pkcompat
  python3-distupgrade python3-lxml qtdeclarative5-accounts-plugin
  qtdeclarative5-dialogs-plugin qtdeclarative5-localstorage-plugin
  qtdeclarative5-privatewidgets-plugin qtdeclarative5-qtfeedback-plugin
  qtdeclarative5-qtquick2-plugin qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-ui-extras-browser-plugin
  qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-ui-toolkit-plugin qtdeclarative5-window-plugin remmina
  remmina-common remmina-plugin-rdp remmina-plugin-vnc rfkill shotwell
  shotwell-common signon-plugin-oauth2 signon-ui signond stk
  system-config-printer-common system-config-printer-udev systemd-shim totem
  totem-common totem-plugins transmission-common transmission-gtk
  ubuntu-minimal ubuntu-release-upgrader-core ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk
  ubuntu-standard ubuntu-wallpapers unity-control-center-signon unity-greeter
  unity-voice-service unity-webapps-qml vino virtualbox virtualbox-dkms
  virtualbox-qt webapp-container webbrowser-app
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 231 not upgraded.
542 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

I say yes, and get the following error:

```
E: Can not write log (Is /dev/pts mounted?) - posix_openpt (2: No such file or directory)
Setting up procps (1:3.3.9-1ubuntu8) ...
update-rc.d: warning: start and stop actions are no longer supported; falling back to defaults
insserv: Service mountkernfs has to be enabled to start service procps
insserv: exiting now!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing package procps (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of udev:
 udev depends on procps; however:
  Package procps is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package udev (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of bluez:
 bluez depends on udev (>= 170-1); however:
  Package udev is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package bluez (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of plymouth:
 plymouth depends on udev (>= 166-0ubuntu4); however:
  Package udev is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package plymouth (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mountall:
 mountall depends on udev; however:
  Package udev is not configured yet.
 mountall depends on plymouth; however:
  Package plymouth is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mountall (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of cmake:
 cmake depends on procps; however:
  Package procps is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package cmake (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of samba:
 samba depends on procps; however:
  Package procps is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package samba (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of winbind:
 winbind depends on samba (= 2:4.1.13+dfsg-4ubuntu3); however:
  Package samba is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package winbind (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libnss-winbind:amd64:
 libnss-winbind:amd64 depends on winbind (= 2:4.1.13+dfsg-4ubuntu3); however:
  Package winbind is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libnss-winbind:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libpam-winbind:amd64:
 libpam-winbind:amd64 depends on winbind (= 2:4.1.13+dfsg-4ubuntu3); however:
  Package winbind is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libpam-winbind:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of lightdm:
 lightdm depends on plymouth (>= 0.8.8-0ubuntu18); however:
  Package plymouth is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package lightdm (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ubuntu-drivers-common:
 ubuntu-drivers-common depends on udev (>= 204-0ubuntu4~); however:
  Package udev is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package ubuntu-drivers-common (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of nvidia-prime:
 nvidia-prime depends on lightdm (>= 1.9.1) | gdm | kdm | sddm; however:
  Package lightdm is not configured yet.
  Package gdm is not installed.
  Package kdm is not installed.
  Package sddm is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package nvidia-prime (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of wine1.6:
 wine1.6 depends on procps; however:
  Package procps is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package wine1.6 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of wine1.6-i386:
 wine1.6-i386 depends on wine1.6:any (= 1:1.6.2-0ubuntu8.1); however:
  Package wine1.6 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package wine1.6-i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of plymouth-theme-ubuntu-text:
 plymouth-theme-ubuntu-text depends on plymouth; however:
  Package plymouth is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package plymouth-theme-ubuntu-text (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of apport-gtk:
 apport-gtk depends on procps; however:
  Package procps is not configured yet.

No apport report written because MaxReports is reached alreadydpkg: error processing package apport-gtk (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured

No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of software-properties-gtk:
 software-properties-gtk depends on ubuntu-drivers-common (>= 1:0.2.75); however:
  Package ubuntu-drivers-common is not configured yet.

No apport report written because MaxReports is reached alreadydpkg: error processing package software-properties-gtk (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured

No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of apturl:
 apturl depends on software-properties-gtk; however:
  Package software-properties-gtk is not configured yet.

No apport report written because MaxReports is reached alreadydpkg: error processing package apturl (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured

No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of bluez-alsa:amd64:
 bluez-alsa:amd64 depends on bluez; however:
  Package bluez is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package bluez-alsa:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of cups:
 cups depends on procps; however:
  Package procps is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package cups (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of printer-driver-hpcups:
 printer-driver-hpcups depends on cups (>= 1.4.0) | cupsddk; however:
  Package cups is not configured yet.
  Package cupsddk is not installed.
 printer-driver-hpcups depends on cups; however:
  Package cups is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package printer-driver-hpcups (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of hplip:
 hplip depends on printer-driver-hpcups (= 3.15.2-0ubuntu4.2); however:
  Package printer-driver-hpcups is not configured yet.
 hplip depends on cups (>= 1.1.20); however:
  Package cups is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package hplip (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached alreadydpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of printer-driver-postscript-hp:
 printer-driver-postscript-hp depends on hplip (>= 3.15.2-0ubuntu4.2); however:
  Package hplip is not configured yet.


dpkg: error processing package printer-driver-postscript-hp (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached alreadydpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of bluez-cups:
 bluez-cups depends on cups; however:
  Package cups is not configured yet.


dpkg: error processing package bluez-cups (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of udisks2:
 udisks2 depends on udev; however:
  Package udev is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package udisks2 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-checkbox-support:
 python3-checkbox-support depends on udev; however:
  Package udev is not configured yet.
 python3-checkbox-support depends on udisks2; however:
  Package udisks2 is not configured yet.

No apport report written because MaxReports is reached alreadydpkg: error processing package python3-checkbox-support (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured

No apport report written because MaxReports is reached alreadydpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-checkbox-ng:
 python3-checkbox-ng depends on python3-checkbox-support; however:
  Package python3-checkbox-support is not configured yet.


dpkg: error processing package python3-checkbox-ng (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of checkbox-ng:
 checkbox-ng depends on python3-checkbox-ng (= 0.3.1-1); however:
  Package python3-checkbox-ng is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package checkbox-ng (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached alreadydpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of checkbox-ng-service:
 checkbox-ng-service depends on checkbox-ng (= 0.3.1-1); however:
  Package checkbox-ng is not configured yet.


dpkg: error processing package checkbox-ng-service (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of checkbox-gui:
 checkbox-gui depends on checkbox-ng-service; however:
  Package checkbox-ng-service is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package checkbox-gui (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of upower:
 upower depends on udev; however:
  Package udev is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package upower (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached alreadydpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gnome-applets:
 gnome-applets depends on upower; however:
  Package upower is not configured yet.


dpkg: error processing package gnome-applets (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of indicator-power:
 indicator-power depends on upower; however:
  Package upower is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package indicator-power (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached alreadydpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gnome-bluetooth:
 gnome-bluetooth depends on bluez (>= 4.36); however:
  Package bluez is not configured yet.
 gnome-bluetooth depends on udev (>= 154); however:
  Package udev is not configured yet.


dpkg: error processing package gnome-bluetooth (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of indicator-bluetooth:
 indicator-bluetooth depends on bluez (>= 4.36); however:
  Package bluez is not configured yet.
 indicator-bluetooth depends on gnome-bluetooth | ubuntu-system-settings; however:
  Package gnome-bluetooth is not configured yet.
  Package ubuntu-system-settings is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package indicator-bluetooth (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of unity-control-center:
 unity-control-center depends on indicator-bluetooth; however:
  Package indicator-bluetooth is not configured yet.
 unity-control-center depends on indicator-power; however:
  Package indicator-power is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package unity-control-center (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gnome-disk-utility:
 gnome-disk-utility depends on udisks2 (>= 2.1.1); however:
  Package udisks2 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package gnome-disk-utility (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gnome-power-manager:
 gnome-power-manager depends on upower (>= 0.99); however:
  Package upower is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package gnome-power-manager (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gnome-session-bin:
 gnome-session-bin depends on upower (>= 0.9.0); however:
  Package upower is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package gnome-session-bin (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of media-player-info:
 media-player-info depends on udev; however:
  Package udev is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package media-player-info (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of plymouth-label:
 plymouth-label depends on plymouth (= 0.9.0-0ubuntu9); however:
  Package plymouth is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package plymouth-label (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of plymouth-theme-ubuntu-logo:
 plymouth-theme-ubuntu-logo depends on plymouth; however:
  Package plymouth is not configured yet.
 plymouth-theme-ubuntu-logo depends on plymouth-label; however:
  Package plymouth-label is not configured yet.

No apport report written because MaxReports is reached alreadydpkg: error processing package plymouth-theme-ubuntu-logo (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured

No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of printer-driver-gutenprint:
 printer-driver-gutenprint depends on cups (>= 1.3.0); however:
  Package cups is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package printer-driver-gutenprint (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of printer-driver-splix:
 printer-driver-splix depends on cups (>= 1.5.0-3~); however:
  Package cups is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package printer-driver-splix (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of rhythmbox:
 rhythmbox depends on media-player-info; however:
  Package media-player-info is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package rhythmbox (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached alreadydpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of rhythmbox-plugins:
 rhythmbox-plugins depends on rhythmbox (= 3.1-1ubuntu3); however:
  Package rhythmbox is not configured yet.


dpkg: error processing package rhythmbox-plugins (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of rhythmbox-plugin-zeitgeist:
 rhythmbox-plugin-zeitgeist depends on rhythmbox (>= 3.1-1ubuntu3); however:
  Package rhythmbox is not configured yet.
 rhythmbox-plugin-zeitgeist depends on rhythmbox (<< 3.2); however:
  Package rhythmbox is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package rhythmbox-plugin-zeitgeist (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of rhythmbox-plugin-cdrecorder:
 rhythmbox-plugin-cdrecorder depends on rhythmbox (= 3.1-1ubuntu3); however:
  Package rhythmbox is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package rhythmbox-plugin-cdrecorder (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached alreadydpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of rhythmbox-mozilla:
 rhythmbox-mozilla depends on rhythmbox (= 3.1-1ubuntu3); however:
  Package rhythmbox is not configured yet.


dpkg: error processing package rhythmbox-mozilla (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached alreadydpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of rhythmbox-plugin-magnatune:
 rhythmbox-plugin-magnatune depends on rhythmbox (= 3.1-1ubuntu3); however:
  Package rhythmbox is not configured yet.


dpkg: error processing package rhythmbox-plugin-magnatune (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: too many errors, stopping
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
Errors were encountered while processing:
 procps
 udev
 bluez
 plymouth
 mountall
 cmake
 samba
 winbind
 libnss-winbind:amd64
 libpam-winbind:amd64
 lightdm
 ubuntu-drivers-common
 nvidia-prime
 wine1.6
 wine1.6-i386
 plymouth-theme-ubuntu-text
 apport-gtk
 software-properties-gtk
 apturl
 bluez-alsa:amd64
 cups
 printer-driver-hpcups
 hplip
 printer-driver-postscript-hp
 bluez-cups
 udisks2
 python3-checkbox-support
 python3-checkbox-ng
 checkbox-ng
 checkbox-ng-service
 checkbox-gui
 upower
 gnome-applets
 indicator-power
 gnome-bluetooth
 indicator-bluetooth
 unity-control-center
 gnome-disk-utility
 gnome-power-manager
 gnome-session-bin
 media-player-info
 plymouth-label
 plymouth-theme-ubuntu-logo
 printer-driver-gutenprint
 printer-driver-splix
 rhythmbox
 rhythmbox-plugins
 rhythmbox-plugin-zeitgeist
 rhythmbox-plugin-cdrecorder
 rhythmbox-mozilla
 rhythmbox-plugin-magnatune
Processing was halted because there were too many errors.
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Trouble writing to disk makes me think you have a full partition or improper mapping or some such thing. Try a "df -h" to check.

Comment: I was able to continue by doing an apt-get autoclean

Comment: Excellent. You can post your own solution as an answer, and after a delay, accept it. Others searching for the same problem can benefit. :-)

Comment: Did you do 'apt-get update' before you tried the original upgrade? What happened when you tried what Ubuntu suggested - 'apt-get autoremove'?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was able to fix this by running the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo do-release-upgrade
```